# Kotlin Multiplatform - Generating JS library (nodejs module)

Tags: node.js, npm, kotlin-multiplatform

`./gradlew jsJar (assemble)` is not creating `package.json` in jar.
What is the best way to create a zip /publish an npm module using kotlin multiplatform?
However, I can see the package.json is created in *`build/js/packages/{myproject}/`* folder during the build process.

Comment: What version of Kotlin do you use? The problem was fixed in 1.4.0 - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-30619. Can you attach a sample project?